# How to add parameter of type array of object, in Array of Object Dynamically in Javascript/Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, key-value

Defined one Array of Object as:

```
"data": {
    "primary":[
        { "menuOptions":
            { "title": 'title1',
              "sortOrder": 1},
          "status": 1,
          "menuType": 'header',
          "MenuID": 'AB1CD' 
        },
        { "menuOptions":
           { "title": 'title2',
             "sortOrder": 2},
          "status": 1,
          "menuType": 'header',
          "MenuID": 'EF2GH' 
       }
  ]
}
```

And want to add one more parameter of type array named SubMenu in `data.primary.SubMenu`, to each object. 
For now want to assign as `[]`.

Expected Object after adding Submenu parameter:

```
"data": {
        "primary":[
            { "menuOptions":
                { "title": 'title1',
                  "sortOrder": 1},
              "status": 1,
              "menuType": 'header',
              "MenuID": 'AB1CD',
              "SubMenu": [
                  {
                      "menuOptions":
                          { "title": 'subtitle1',
                            "sortOrder": 1},
                      "status": 1,
                      "menuType": 'header',
                      "MenuID": 'AB1CD1'
                  }
              ]
            },
            { "menuOptions":
               { "title": 'title2',
                 "sortOrder": 2},
              "status": 1,
              "menuType": 'header',
              "MenuID": 'EF2GH',
              "SubMenu": []
           }
      ]
    }
```

Tried ways to do that,

- Used Object.assign()
- Used Array.push()
- Used Array.push(Object.assign())
- Used data.primary[0].newProperty = [] and then push one object in to that array.
  But it does not show when try to console.log() **data.primary[0]**.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
data.primary.map(d=>{
       d.SubMenu = // your value 
})


console.log(data)
```

Comment: Having same issue as mentioned in other comments.

Comment: Array.map doesn't change the original array, it creates and returns a new one with the changes to each element applied.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign the object to the new parameter in the existing array of object. Below is the example for assigning one object to the new parameter (i.e. SubMenu). If you want to assign it to every object use foreach loop and assign it in same way as shown below.

```js
data.primary.SubMenu = [{
  "menuOptions": {
    "title:"
    'subtitle1',
    "sortOrder": 1
  },
  "status": 1,
  "menuType": 'header',
  "MenuID": 'AB1CD1'
}]
```

Comment: It didn't work as expected. The expected response I've mentioned in my Question, for that I've printed **data** but right now I've implemented static assignment as your snippet of code: I have to print **data.primary.SubMenu**.

Comment: Have also tried using forEach loop to assign **[]** to each object in array of **primary**

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate your problem, you have an object with an array of objects in it, and in each of those objects, you need an array named "SubMenu" initialized to an empty array `[]`

```js
const data = {
    "primary":[
        { "menuOptions":
            { "title": 'title1',
              "sortOrder": 1},
          "status": 1,
          "menuType": 'header',
          "MenuID": 'AB1CD' 
        },
        { "menuOptions":
           { "title": 'title2',
             "sortOrder": 2},
          "status": 1,
          "menuType": 'header',
          "MenuID": 'EF2GH' 
       }
  ]
}

//initialize the array in each object
data.primary.forEach(obj => {
obj.SubMenu = [];
})

//push whatever you want in it for the first object
data.primary[0].SubMenu.push({
                      "menuOptions":
                          { "title": 'subtitle1',
                            "sortOrder": 1},
                      "status": 1,
                      "menuType": 'header',
                      "MenuID": 'AB1CD1'
                  })

console.log(data);
```

Comment: There is no change in existing array of object. Not able to get Submenu as shown in expected JSON Object even the ``SubMenu : [] ``

Comment: Do you have the "data" object stored in a variable in your program?

Comment: No data is just part of the Response I used to build, as you've used it in code to store entire primary object. Simply I've just used primary for further logic. But Yes I've initialize `primary` in `data`.